# v-for function that returns an array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

```
<div class="facet-item" v-for="(item, facetItemIndex) in displayFacetItems(facetsIndex)" :key="facetItemIndex">
  <facet v-bind:item="item"  v-bind:facet="facet"></facet>
</div>

displayFacetItems (facetsIndex, searchTerm) {
  if (!searchTerm || searchTerm === '') return this.facets[facetsIndex].facetItems
    return this.facets[facetsIndex].facetItems.filter((facetItem) => {
      return _.includes(facetItem.name.toLowerCase(), searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    })
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the v-for doesn't update when this returns an array of filtered objects:

```
return this.facets[facetsIndex].facetItems.filter((facetItem) => {
  return _.includes(facetItem.name.toLowerCase(), searchTerm.toLowerCase())
})
```

I can get the v-for to update when I do something like this:

```
this.facets[facetsIndex].facetItems = this.facets[facetsIndex].facetItems.filter((facetItem) => {
  return _.includes(facetItem.name.toLowerCase(), searchTerm.toLowerCase())
})
```

But the problem is that this mutates the original array, which I can't have happen.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is `facetsIndex` in your v-for loop ? And where does come from `searchTerm` ? You should create a jsfiddle for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Filtering with Vue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797068/search-filtering-with-vue2)

Comment: @Nic could you tell us the output you are getting from this code you have posted?